# Returning a vector of const elements

Tags: c++

Say I have a class member vector of non-const elements...

How do I return them as const elements, in a member function?

I guess you could do this, but this is making a wasteful copy.

```
std::vector<const int> ExampleClass::get_numbers()
  {
    std::vector<const int> n;
    std::transform(n_.cbegin(), n_.cend(), std::back_inserter(n),[](int v){return v;});
    return n;
  }
```

In the above example n_ is:
`vector<int> ExampleClass::n_`

Comment: That doesn’t make any sense. The vector can’t move the items

Comment: Yeah... this question doesn't make much sense...
I don't see why the API is expecting the vector elements to be const... its making a copy anyways... it is not a const reference being returned... I'll just change the interface.

Comment: What API? No self-respecting API would "expect" a vector of const elements, because it's pretty hard to do something like that, in C++.

Comment: Replace your team?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik here is the API if you are truly interested:
https://github.com/Xilinx/Vitis-AI/blob/master/src/Vitis-AI-Runtime/VART/vart/runner/include/vart/runner.hpp#L157

Comment: When you simplified the example you changed from `const ExampleClass*` to `const int`.  Doesn't make sense with `int`, does with pointers.

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes a big difference. Pro tip: always post real code on Stackoverflow. Fake code only results in fake answers.

Comment: I'd encourage simplified code rather than real code, but you do have to make sure you don't change things when simplifying. Going from `X*` to `const X*` is not the same as going from `int` to `const int`. (Going from `int` to `const int` would correspond to going from `X*` to `X* const` -- constant pointer, not constant pointed-to object.)

Comment: I rephrased the question today, and got a lot more feedback, sharing if you folks are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72916809/better-way-to-give-constant-view-of-pointers-in-c
Will close out this question in a day or so, because it was poorly formed. Thank you all!