# Better way to give constant view of pointers in C++

Tags: c++

I have a class that must return a **constant** view of some pointers to the upper layers of software.

Internally, the pointers must be **non-const**, because the class will need to manipulate the objects internally.

I don't see any option for providing this const view of the pointers to a higher level client, without making a copy of all the pointers. This seems wasteful. What if I was managing millions of objects?

Is there a better way?

Here is some example code:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class example {
public:
  
  example() {
    bytePtrs_.push_back(new char);
    *bytePtrs_[0] = '$';
  }

  // I want to do this, but compiler will not allow
  // error: could not convert ‘((example*)this)->example::bytePtrs_’ from ‘std::vector<char*>’ to ‘std::vector<const char*>’
  std::vector<const char*> getPtrs() { 
    return bytePtrs_; 
  }

  // Must make wasteful copy
  std::vector<const char*> getPtrs() { 
    std::vector<const char*> ret;
    for (auto &ptr : bytePtrs_)
      ret.push_back(ptr);
    return ret; 
  }

private:

  std::vector<char*> bytePtrs_;
};

int main() {

  example e;

  std::vector<const char*> bytePtrs = e.getPtrs();

  std::cout << bytePtrs[0] << std::endl; 

}
```

Comment: In c++ 20, you'll need a view; in previous versions, you might want to implement it for yourself (or simply `reinterpret_cast<>` if you're sure the implementations are the same.

Comment: Does it have to be `std::vector`? Can it be a different class? If the view of the pointers are constant, don't you want to return `const std::vector<...>`? I.e. does the upper layer modify the _count_ of the pointers?

Comment: What do you want to _do_ with the returned vector?  If all you want to do is access the elements contained within it, you might consider `const char *getPtrs() { return bytePtrs_.data(); }`.  Not ideal, I know, since you can't retrieve `size()` this way, but that could always be a separate method.

Comment: The upper layer will want to iterate over the vector and access its elements in read only fashion. Each pointer points to an object with a bunch of metadata needed by the upper layers.

Comment: Which standard are you using? Is `bytePtrs_` going to change between the call to `getPtrs()` and the upper layers consuming its constant view?

Comment: Have you considered using a custom iterator? Is it even viable for your case?

Comment: C++11 right now, but I'm pretty flexible on that, C++20 might be too cutting edge though. No, they shouldn't change, but I need them to be non-const... because the constructor will need to build up this vector of pointers...

Comment: The trouble is someone else defined the interface, and its locked into place... I must return a vector of const pointers...

Comment: Wrote an answer.  You should be able to make `proxy_vector` look sufficiently like `std::vector` to 'fool' any existing client code.  Talk to 'someone else' if needs be.

Comment: And see @bolov's comment about making the class copyable, if that's an issue for you.  That is certainly a weakness of my approach.

Comment: Would `std::vector<std::experimental::propagate_const<char*>> bytePtrs;` ([std::experimental::propagate_const](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const)) be of benefit `?

Comment: @WilderField what is the type that your external API expects? `std::vector<const char*>`?, a pair of two random access iterators with `const char*` value type, anything else? Forgive me if I sound pushy, but the exact datatype is crucial here.

Comment: If you really cannot change absolutely anything in clients code, there's always an option of keeping `std::vector<const char*> bytePtrsConst_` as a copy and doubling the logic to keep the state consistent. Not a good solution, but maybe worth pointing out.

Comment: This is the real scenario. There is an abstract base class that defines the interface, and at the moment, I must comply: 
https://github.com/Xilinx/Vitis-AI/blob/master/src/Vitis-AI-Runtime/VART/vart/runner/include/vart/runner.hpp#L157

Comment: @WilderField it returns by value (so copies) anyway. I'd just do `std::vector<char*> x;` then `return std::vector<const char*>(x.begin(), x.end())` and don't bother.

Comment: @alagner you are right... say we were to redesign this API... the better choice would be return const reference to vector of const elements? Or something better exists? If you write answer, I will accept it. By design this API makes copy, so why am I asking about how to avoid copy...

Comment: @WilderField here comes the answer ;) As for the design choice: you tell me. If you really want to avoid copying and need this `T* -> const T*` transition I'd go with a pair of customized iterators. But it really depends. BTW, the API can also be expanded instead of redesigning as a opt-in should the user really want to avoid copying. I'd ask there: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ if I were you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP has pointed out in one of the comments, this is the API the code needs to comply to:
https://github.com/Xilinx/Vitis-AI/blob/master/src/Vitis-AI-Runtime/VART/vart/runner/include/vart/runner.hpp#L157

So by design it returns by copy, which is unavoidable really, thus what really can be done is this:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class example {
public:
  
  example() {
    bytePtrs_.push_back(new char);
    *bytePtrs_[0] = '$';
  }

  // Returning by value
  // so shallow copy of objects is expected
  // i.e. the pointers are copied
  std::vector<const char*> getPtrs() { 
    return std::vector<const char*>(bytePtrs_.begin(), bytePtrs_.end());
  }

private:

  std::vector<char*> bytePtrs_;
};

int main() {

  example e;

  std::vector<const char*> bytePtrs = e.getPtrs();

  std::cout << bytePtrs[0] << std::endl; 

}
```

Comment: Well, that certainly moves the goalposts.  Looks like they went for the simple option.  OP, how big _is_ that vector?  Copying pointers is cheap, unless there are zillions of them, and you might be in danger of micro-optimising here.  But if you are considering changing the API (or maybe layering something on top of it? - not sure if that's possible) then I like the custom iterators idea.  Simple, efficient and effective.

Comment: @PaulSanders sorry to move the goal post, but wouldn't you agree that the function signature is return by value, by definition? So perhaps the original question was naive? Return by value always makes a copy right? Or is there chance for return value optimization where that would not occur?

Comment: No, it makes a copy (assuming it's returning an existing object).  RVO would only apply where you return an object that is created withing the body of the function itself, and that appears not to be the case here.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this using [std::experimental::propagate_const](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const).

That will forward the *constness* of the pointer onto the pointed-to object.

```
#include <experimental/propagate_const>

class example {
public:

//  using vector = std::vector<char*>>;
    using vector = std::vector<std::experimental::propagate_const<char*>>;

    example() {
        bytePtrs.push_back(new char);
        *bytePtrs[0] = '$';
    }

    vector const& getPtrs() const {
        return bytePtrs;
    }

private:

    vector bytePtrs;
};

int main()
{
    example e;

    example::vector const& bytePtrs = e.getPtrs();

    // dereference this or add a null terminator
    std::cout << *bytePtrs[0] << std::endl; // fine and dandy

    *bytePtrs[0] = 'x'; // compile error
}
```

Comment: In `main()` you would want `std::cout << *bytePtrs[0] << std::endl`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider returning a [proxy object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) when you only want to permit `const` access, something like this (edited to fix the massive hole in the original code pointed out by @alagner!):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class T> class proxy_vector
{
public:
    proxy_vector (const std::vector<T *> &v) : m_v (v) { }
    size_t size () { return m_v.size (); }
    const T * const &operator[] (size_t i) const { return m_v [i]; }
    // ... more functions as needed
private:
    const std::vector <T *> &m_v;
};

class example
{
public:
    example() : m_pv (bytePtrs_)
    {
        bytePtrs_.push_back(new char);
        *bytePtrs_[0] = '$';
    }

    const proxy_vector <char> &getPtrs() { return m_pv; }

private:
    std::vector<char*> bytePtrs_;
    proxy_vector <char> m_pv;
};

int main()
{
    example e;
    auto &bytePtrs = e.getPtrs ();
//  *bytePtrs [0] = 'x';    // uncomment to show that this code now actually works as intended!
    std::cout << bytePtrs[0] << "\n";
}
```

A decent compiler should optimise most, if not all, of this away.  Add access methods to `proxy vector` as needed, I doubt you will need many.

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yZD9duC1gNBc2mVb) (seems to work fine in C++11).

---

What @alagner suggests should also work and might be simpler.  I haven't thought that through.

Comment: I like the proxy ideea. But the implementation is not too strong. It's too much work. Plus it's non copyable which makes `example` non copyable. Attempting to make it copyable is duable but a head ache and prone to bugs.

Comment: @bolov _It's too much work_ Hardly!  But your second point is a good one, maybe `m_pv` should be a pointer if such an object needs to be copyable (although then you'd need a custom copy constructor etc, which is not great).  But, it may well be that it doesn't need to be.

Comment: @PaulSanders *It would need custom copy constructor* - not necessarily, depends on the expected use case for this proxy object. If it's a view-like object, it would be expected that it does a shallow copy with no copying of underlying data. Raw, non-owning pointer to data could be fine for this use.

Comment: @PaulSanders maybe I'm missing sth, but doesn't that just return sth like `const vector<char*>` and the OP needs `vector<const char*>`?

Comment: @alagner The key to this is that the proxy object only permits `const` access to the underlying pointers.  If you look at its public API, that's what it does.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Sorry, what I meant was that `class example` would need a custom copy constructor.  Otherwise, `m_pv` ends up pointing at the wrong vector in the copy (eeeeeeeee!).  But if the class doesn't need to be copyable / moveable, just `= delete` all those guys (and I'm hoping that suits the OP's use case, because bolov's right, custom copy constructors are a pain).  Maybe there's a better way to make `example` copyable, but it's too hot and too late here to think about that today.

Comment: @PaulSanders I allowed myself to test your code, see here: https://godbolt.org/z/ajjbs9Ybo
Remarks in the code as comments, I hope you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @alagner Sorry, I don't understand what you're getting at.  If I 'uncomment below' (the first commented out line), I get a compiler error (which is what we want, no?).  I defy you to gain write access via `proxy_vector`! :)

Comment: @PaulSanders then check line 36. My point is that your code does not have `const char*` semantic, rather `char* const`. I guess what you've meant should be sth like this:
https://godbolt.org/z/GTjE6xzjE (skipped templated proxy for brevity).

Comment: @alagner OK, I get it now.  [Edit] But I need to get the template to work, give me a mo.

Comment: @PaulSanders take your time. I stripped that templated code because of how much cumbersome all the `remove_cv_t` `add_pointer_t` and the rest of those templates can get, especially when writing a quick example. ;)

Comment: Problem is, you'll lose the ability to pass it to a few algorithms (both std and custom libraries that actually take `const std::vector<>&`).

Comment: @alagner Got it now I think.  My stars weren't aligned :)  Many thanks for pointing out the (gigantic!) flaw in the original.  Didn't need to employ any of the trickery you talked about (but maybe a more robust solution would need them).

Comment: @lorro Sure, it all depends on what the OP really needs.  `begin()` and `end()` would be obvious things to add, as he talks about 'iterating' through the data.

Comment: @PaulSanders don't mention it, misaligned stars happen to every single one of us. Unless its safe Rust maybe, but then the compiler keeps yelling ;)

Answer (score -1):

This is one of the very few cases where `reinterpret_cast<>` could be allowed into the code I think: since the `std::vector<char *>` and `const std::vector<const char*>&` are *assumed* to be compatible in memory anyways, you might cast. Thus, `getPtrs()` could actually return `reinterpret_cast<const std::vector<const char*>&>(bytePtrs_);`. To be clear: this is an optimization that relies on concrete ABI details (ItaniumABI et. al.), not generic standard C++, but I'm not yet aware of any architecture where it wouldn't work.

In c++20 and later, you might consider checking `std::ranges::view`.

Comment: Except that you can't `reinterpret_cast` `std::vector<char*>` to `std::vector<const char*>`: https://godbolt.org/z/he59oxGsd

Comment: you can't reinterpret between `vector<T>` and `vector<U>` even if `T` and `U` are related or compatible

Comment: @Yksisarvinen fixed, const ref works.

Comment: @bolov they are not only compatible, they have the same memory layout in ItaniumABI. so you can.

Comment: @lorro you are not allowed. You are not even allowed to reinterpret cast between `struct A { int x; };` and `struct B { int x };` See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46044783/2805305 with standard quotes

Comment: This is compiling, and functioning, but I don't understand if this is making a copy or not, do I need to change the return type of the class method to avoid a copy?
```
  std::vector<const char*> getPtrs() {
    return reinterpret_cast<const std::vector<const char*>&>(bytePtrs_);
  }

Comment: @WilderField It's making a copy because you assign the result to new variable in `main`. And I'm not really convinced about "functioning", it makes my UB senses tingling, can't say if this is valid C++ or not.

Comment: I agree, I also don't know if this is UB, but I get the dollar sign printed out.

Comment: This is Undefined Behavior! `std::vector<char*>` and `std::vector<const char*>` are two different classes that are unrelated and aliasing one as another is Undefined Behavior. It doesn't matter if they have the same layout or whatnot. See my previous comment with standard quotes.

Comment: I really appreciate everyone's input on this question!

Comment: Moreover in practice the most likely issue to arise from this UB is not memory layout access but from the assumption that an access though one of them will not affect the other one (because they cannot be legally aliased - a contract which you broke) so it can reorder operations in a way that affects the observable behavior or even completely remove memory access replacing them with memorized values (which now do not correspond anymore whit the actual value). This is the most likely problem that can appear in practice, but the nature of UB makes it so that any kind of waky behavior can appear.

Comment: @bolov Following your logic, taking a `char*` and storing in a `const char*` would also mean such memoizing problems. No - on ItaniumABI (and many other ABIs), this is the same memory layout, so it works. That doesn't make it _standard_ C++, but it works - and OP's request implicitly assumed that `vector<char*>` and `vector<const char*>` should somehow be the same (OP wants to spare the copy loop). I currently cannot think of an ABI where it doesn't work (and have 6-7 architectures at hand) - I agree that it's non-standard, but OP was looking for optimization.

Comment: @lorro I appreciate your suggestion, I had no idea this was even possible, so I learned something from you :-)

Comment: @lorro no. Aliasing `char *` via a `const char*` pointer is perfectly legal and OK. Please try and consider what I am saying. This has nothing to to with ABIs and memory layout. As I've given an example this is about breaking the C++ strict aliasing rules and having Undefined Behavior. I also state that this UB is not merely a "theoretical" never to be a problem in practice. It's a very dangerous issue that will most likely generate "buggy" executables (example in next comment).

Comment: @lorro My first comment covers the standard rules and why this is UB in C++. Now I wrote a small very simple program to illustrate the actual practical issues I am talking about. The actual real-life bugs that this code will introduce in the program: https://godbolt.org/z/9coT77cYf

Comment: @bolov I’ve read your comment and the example. Noone argues that it’s ABI-dependent (i.e., non-standard). However, you won’t modify `const vector<const char*>&`, as it’s const - hence the case you’ve mentioned won’t occur.

Comment: @lorro that is just one example. Because it's UB anything can happen and that should be enough to not write UB code , but I wanted to go the extra mile and show you a practical example where this will actually introduce hard to find bugs. And ... yes, it **can** happen: the compiler stores the buffer pointer from the const reference, then does a push_back on the original object, that incurs a relocation, then to code does an access via the const one but it uses the saved buffer pointer which now points to invalid memory => extremely difficult to find bug.

Comment: @bolov According to your logic, it also would be incorrect code if a different thread modified a vector (strictly guarded by global mutex) to whoch I have a read-only reference. I’m aware of what UB is. I’m also aware that the ABI defines the behavior in many cases where the standard says UB (not only IBD). Hence the idea.

Comment: I understand the temptation to hold on for dear life on an ideea, solution that is yours. But shouldn't it be more exciting to learn something new, to have a new tool in your toolbox you can use from now on? To know you won't write the same wrong code again? Just some food for thought. I've shown you both the theoretical rules and the practical implications. It's up to you what you do with this information.

Comment: @bolov I don't think I'd like to continue arguing with you, this tone I find personalizing. Also we're talking about orthogonal things: you're citing that purely by standard it's UB (which we agree) and tell how you imagine optimization could speculatively be done; I'm telling the results of ItaniumABI analysis (where it's defined) and how gcc / clang compiler and optimizer works. I'm ok to receive a -1 vote from you on this.

Comment: @lorro I am not sure, but don't gcc and clang use the Itanium ABI on x86-64? The godbolt link I sent you shows code generated on x86-64 and it shows the bug that appears when you alias the 2 types. And to be clear: the bug is in the user written code, not in the compiler generated assembly.